# Can a subgroup of the symmetric group $\mathfrak S_k$ be an elementary substructure?

Tags: group-theory, logic, predicate-logic, model-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $\mathfrak A \subset \mathfrak B$ be two $\mathcal L$-structures over the language $\mathcal L$. $\mathfrak A$ is an elemetary substructure of $\mathfrak B$ if for all $\mathcal L$-formulas and all assignments $\alpha: \mathcal V \to A$ we have $\mathfrak A \vDash \varphi[\alpha] \iff \mathfrak B \vDash \varphi[\alpha]$, where $\mathcal V$ is the set of variables of $\mathcal L$, $A\subset B$ are the constants sets of the two structures $\mathfrak A$ and $\mathfrak B$.

My question is about the symmetric group $\mathfrak S_k$ of premutations $\sigma: K \to K$, where $K= \{1,...,k\} \subset \mathbb N$.

My idea is that any nontrivial subgroup $\mathfrak S'_r \subset \mathfrak S_k$ (which is a substructure) is not elementary, where $r<k$. Because the formula $\varphi(x_1,\cdots,x_r) \equiv \forall v (v = x_1 \lor \cdots \lor v = x_r)$ which is valid in $\mathfrak A$ under any assignement $\alpha: \mathcal V \to A$ is not valid in $\mathfrak B$.

It seems that no substructure can be an elementary substructure because of the that formula. What is wrong ?

Comment: yes, your proof works! and we can in fact say something even stronger. if $M$ is any finite $\mathcal{L}$-structure, then $M$ not only has no proper elementary substructures, but it does not even have any proper substructures that are *[elementarily equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_equivalence)* to it! this is because the sentence "there exist exactly $n$ elements" is expressible in any first-order language, for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Exactly ! I thought about it. It seemed to me that If the structure at hand is finite then it can have no substructure that is elemntary substructure because of that formula.

Comment: Please don't use math mode for emphasis, it looks horrible... Just put the text between asterisks instead, *like this* rather than $like\ this$.

Comment: @HansLundmark In the title you mean ? look at it now

Comment: Hmm... I just realized that this kind of formatting doesn't work in titles (by design, for reasons discussed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285727/allow-some-markdown-in-question-titles) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237125/can-we-get-markdown-support-in-questions-title-field), for example). I would suggest removing the emphasis altogether then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. In fact it has nothing to do with symmetric groups per se: no finite structure ever has (proper) elementary substructures, or proper elementary *extensions* for that matter by exactly the same argument!

There are a couple points worth making, however:

- Of course the argument above fails badly for infinite structures, and in fact the situation for infinite structures is highly nontrivial. By [compactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem) (in the form of the [upward Lowenheim-Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem#Upward_part)) every infinite structure whatsoever has lots of proper elementary extensions. The situation for elementary substructures is a bit more complicated. Say that a $\Sigma$-structure $\mathcal{A}$ is *big relative to its language* iff $\vert\mathcal{A}\vert>\aleph_0+\vert\Sigma\vert$. The [downward Lowennheim-Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem#Downward_part) (which contra the upward version is unrelated to compactness) says that every structure which is big relative to its language has proper elementary submodels. Finally, if $\mathcal{A}$ is not big relative to its language then $\mathcal{A}$ may or may not have proper elementary substructures (compare e.g. $(\mathbb{N};<)$ and $(\mathbb{Q};<)$).
- Equality plays a crucial role in your argument. If we look at *equality-free* first-order logic we see a very different picture. Specifically, every logic $\mathcal{L}$ *(there are many logics out there besides first-order logic!)* has a corresponding notion of elementary substructurehood $\preccurlyeq_\mathcal{L}$, namely $\mathcal{M}\preccurlyeq_\mathcal{L}\mathcal{N}$ iff $\mathcal{M}$ is a substructure of $\mathcal{N}$ and $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ agree about the truth value of all $\mathcal{L}$-sentences with parameters from $\mathcal{M}$. Equality-free first-order logic - which I'll call "$\mathsf{FOL_{w/o=}}$" although that's not standard - consists of all formulas and sentences in first-order logic that don't involve "$=$." There turn out to be a number of differences between $\mathsf{FOL}$ and $\mathsf{FOL_{w/o=}}$, including as regards their elementary substructurehood notions. For example, if $X\subsetneq Y$ are finite sets (thought of as structures in the empty language) then of course $X\not\preccurlyeq Y$ but we can show $X\preccurlyeq_{\mathsf{FOL_{w/o=}}}Y$. [This answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4133440/28111) may be useful here, the connection being that if $\mathcal{A}$ is a substructure of $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{A}$ is quasi-isomorphic (using the terminology of that answer) to $\mathcal{B}$ then $\mathcal{A}\preccurlyeq_{\mathsf{FOL_{w/o=}}}\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: @Physor *Some* infinite structures have no proper elementary substructures - e.g. $(\mathbb{N};<)$ (this is a good exercise). I'll add more detail in a few minutes (I'm in a meeting right now).

Comment: I think you had to write ... "Of course this *can* fail badly for infinite structures, but doesn't always" right ?

Comment: @Physor I meant that the general principle "No --- structures have proper elementary substructures" fails badly, but you're right, I could have been clearer. (I'll edit in a bit - again, meeting.)

Comment: @Physor I've elaborated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you please explain something for the 1st point, and namely: you mean the examples $(\mathbb{N};<)$ and $(\mathbb{Q};<)$ seperately, and not $(\mathbb{N};<) \subset (\mathbb{Q};<)$ (one as substructure of the other) , right ? I mean I can show for any subset of $\mathbb{N}$ with the same ordering that it is a substructure but not an elementary. For the $\mathbb{Q}$ which is a dense linear order (DLO) I couldn't yet do the same.

Comment: @Physor I meant that $(\mathbb{N};<)$ is an example of an infinite structure which is not big relative to its language and has no proper elementary substructures, while $(\mathbb{Q};<)$ is an example of an infinite structure which is not big relative to its language and does have proper elementary substructures (e.g. the dyadic rationals).